# SAS EG (SQL) deleting rows where max value in one column using double group by

Tags: sql, group-by, sas

I need to delete all the rows with a max value of `duty_per_id` where the `rotn_prng_nbr` and `empl_nbr` are the same (not the same to each other, but the max where of all of the rows where those two remain constant). From the table below it should delete rows 3,7 and 9.

| rotn_prng_nbr | empl_nbr | duty_perd_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B93 | 12 | 1 |
| B93 | 12 | 2 |
| B93 | 12 | 3 |
| B21 | 12 | 1 |
| B21 | 12 | 2 |
| B21 | 12 | 3 |
| B21 | 12 | 4 |
| B21 | 18 | 1 |
| B21 | 18 | 2 |

using SAS EG.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.duty_perd_id < (select max(t2.duty_perd_id)
                        from t t2
                        where t2.rotn_prng_nbr = t.rotn_prng_nbr and
                              t2.empl_nbr = t.empl_nbr
                       );
```

Comment: sorry for the late response here, but what exactly is t2 in this code?

Comment: @MichaelAncel . . . `t2` is a table alias for the table you are using.  It is defined in the subquery to enable the correlation clause.

Comment: thanks! I got it to work, but this solution is still really slow to run. I opened a new post if you are interested, but either way I appreciate the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67973562/sas-eg-sql-deleting-rows-where-max-value-in-one-column